# Getter not reactive when updating the property of an object in Vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I am experiencing a few issues regarding reactivity in my application.

I have a Vuex store where I have an object 'songs' containing 'song' objects where the key is their id. For each song object within, I have various properties, with the one in question being 'playing' a boolean value.

e.g.

```js
songs = {
   2: {playing: false},
   7: {playing: true)
}
```

Within my application I have a list, using v-for for all these songs with a button that toggles the playing property of the song. When the button is pressed I dispatch the action I have created passing in the songid associated with the button that has been pressed

```js
this.$store.dispatch('toggleSongPlaying', {songid: songid})
```

Depending on whether the song is playing or not, I wish to display the appropriate icon.

My simplified vuex store for my issue consists of the following:

```js
const state = {
  songs: {}
};

const mutations = {
  update_song_playing(state, payload) {
     var songObj = state.songs[payload.songid]
     var playingBool = !songObj.playing
     Vue.set(songObj, 'playing', playingBool)
  }
};

const actions = {
  toggleSongPlaying({ commit }, payload) {
     commit("update_song_playing", payload)
  }
};

const getters = {
  getSongs: state => state.songs
};
```

The setting functionality is working fine, the issue is with reactivity. When the toggle button is pressed, the icon change does not occur. Triggering a rerender does however result in the icon changing. Within my component, I am using mapGetters like so:

```js
computed: {
    ...mapGetters({
      songs: "getSongs"
    })
}
```

Is there something I am missing in order to get reactivity to work correctly with this nested object?

Thanks for any suggestions!

EDIT - Template code for list and icons

```js
<v-list dense>
   <v-subheader>Songs List</v-subheader>
   <v-list-item-group v-model="activeSong" color="primary">
         <v-list-item
              v-for="(song, songID) in songs"
              :key="songID"
         >
               <v-icon class="mr-3" @click.stop="toggleSongPlaying(songID)">{{song.playing ? 'mdi-pause' : 'mdi-play'}}</v-icon>

                // song details etc...
                <v-list-item-content>
                    <v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-title>
                </v-list-item-content>
                    
          </v-list-item>
   </v-list-item-group>
</v-list>
```

```
methods: {
   toggleSongPlaying(songid) {
       this.$store.dispatch('toggleSongPlaying', {songid: songid})
   }
},
```

EDIT2
In a separate component in created, I populate the songs object with a song like so

```
created() {
    var songid = "12"
    var song = {
        length: ...,
        playing: false,
    }

    var payload = {
        song: song,
        songid: songid
    }

    this.$store.dispatch('addSong', payload)
},
```

Within Vuex

Action:

```
addSong({ commit }, payload) {
   commit("add_song", payload);
}
```

Mutator:

```
add_song(state, payload) {
    state.songs[payload.songid] = payload.song
},
```

Comment: Within the component, it calls the toggleSongPlaying action.

Comment: I've just added it at the bottom. When I press the icon to toggle the boolean variable no change occurs. But if a rerender occurs such as clicking on an item in the list, the icon changes

Comment: I've also tried this in the Vuetify sandbox and cannot reproduce the problem

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. For simplicity of my question, I have said that the state songs is initialised with 2 song objects. In practice, I am setting songs in the created hook with a setter taking in the song id and an object consisting of various props including the playing property. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Please show how you are assigning _song_ objects to your store

Comment: Ahh of course, I needed Vue.set in my addSong method!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The way you are assigning songs to your state is not reactive

> [**For Objects**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects)
>
> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion

Change your `add_song` mutation to replace the `songs` state property with a new one, including the new song. This treats `songs` as immutable

```js
add_song: (state, { songid, song }) => {
  state.songs = {
    ...state.songs,
    [ songid ]: { ...song } // break any object references, thank me later
  }
},
```

Now you don't need to use `Vue.set` because the `payload` property has been added reactively. Your `update_song_playing` can simply be

```js
update_song_playing: (state, { songid }) => {
  const song = state.songs[songid];
  if (song) {
    song.playing = !song.playing;
  }
}
```

---

You can also use `Vue.set` in your `add_song` mutation but I've always felt [Flux-based stores work best with immutable data](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/flux-architecture/9781786465818/ch09.html).

Comment: Just in case, `Object.assign(state.songs, ...)` did not work but the equating. Some might find https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep interesting, too. Thank you very much! Purely genius! Purely **awesome**! ✨

Answer (score 0):

Call `$forceUpdate()` after calling your `dispatch` such as:

```js
<v-icon class="mr-3" @click.stop="toggleSongPlaying(songID), $forceUpdate()">{{song.playing ? 'mdi-pause' : 'mdi-play'}}</v-icon>
```